# Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions Finite Element Method

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following problem in Finite Element Method

$$ -(\alpha u')' + \beta u' + \gamma u$$

with $ \Omega = (0, 1)$, $ u(0) = 0 $ and $ u'(1) = 3 $

to be able to write the **weak formulation** of the problem do I need a lifting function?

i.e., do I need to define something like

$$ \tilde u = u - R$$

P.S. Sorry for the tags there is nothing like "finite-element", "neumann-boundary-condition", "dirichlet-boundary-condition", "mixed-boundary-condition"

Comment: I am suggesting this question be migrated to [scicomp.SE]

Comment: Ok. I thought this was the correct place, anyway, how can it be migrated?

Comment: A mod could get the migration done, but if you would ctrl+c&v your question there, that would be ok too.

Comment: The ODE is not properly expressed. Have you premultiplied by a test function and integrate to see what happens?